# What can I use to write a image with GTM?

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager

I have to use a tag img with a dynamic URL, but the custom image option of GTM I can't build the URL dynamic, I can use variables but for example, I cannot do a join to an array.
So I tried `document.write()` the image but it doesn't make any request. The code is similiar to this.

```
<script>
  var data = '<img src="https://dynamicURL.com/?var=test1^test2^test3”>';

  document.write(data);
</script>
```

The option of document.write is turned on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the image to send data to end endpoint you can use the custom image tag template.

If for some reason you insist on custom HTML you can use a custom HTML tag and do:

```
<script>
var img = new Image();
img.src = "https://dynamicURL.com/?var=test1^test2^test3";
</script>
```

Do not use document.write, that's just horrible.

To send data the image does not actually be inserted into the DOM. If you want the image to appear in any specific place you need to select and element, create the Image, and then append the image to the element.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked because when you set the src it loads the image, like it says on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images

Comment: By the way, the only thing I wanted to do was to load the image because they read the query parameters and I don't have to do anything with the image.